# OSX Mojave sysctl -p illegal

Tags: linux, macos, inotify, sysctl

14 "Mojave" on my macbook and I am trying to increase the `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` value in `/etc/sysctl.conf` (to solve another problem). To conclude this rite I need to run `sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`. But I get

```
"illegal option -- p"
```

When I check the man page on osx it in fact does not have the -p option (to supply a file) nor the --system option (to load all known config files); on another system I clearly see that those options are available.

How else then can I get sysctl to take my new configs? Is there a different way to configure `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` on osx?

Comment: `inotify` is specific to the Linux kernel, MacOS has no idea what you're trying to tell it.

Answer (score 0):

On Big Sur, the first lines for `sysctl` manpage are:

```
SYSCTL(8)                 BSD System Manager's Manual                SYSCTL(8)

NAME
     sysctl -- get or set kernel state
```

This must mean `sysctl` itself can be used to update some values. However, `sysctl` does not show the `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` name. Must be another mac thing...

Comment: I just did `sudo sysctl net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive=1` - and it worked!